# Printing the value of EOF

Tags: c, putchar

In Kernighan and Ritchie (the C programming language):

'Write a program to print the value of EOF'

I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

    int c;
    c = getchar();
    if ((c = getchar()) ==  EOF)
        putchar(c);
}
```

but it doesn't output anything Why?

Comment: `EOF` is not a character, therefore `putchar(EOF)` can do anything. What you want is `printf("%d", EOF)`.

Comment: `putchar(EOF)` is defined to mean `putchar( (unsigned char)(EOF) )`  (C11 7.21.7.3)  , so it can't "do anything" as such, it must output some character. Although perhaps that is a non-printable character

Answer (score 19, accepted):

putchar function prints a character.

But EOF is not a character and is used to indicate the End of a file. So the getchar returns a value which is distinguishable from the character sets so as to indicate there is no more input.

So printing EOF using putchar() wont print any values

printing it as integer

```
printf("%d",EOF);
```

gives result **-1**

Comment: Mine gives a result **-1%**, why is that the result when everybody is saying "EOF" isn't a character?

Comment: @MichaelElliott `EOF` is a macro that expands to `-1`  (which is an integer value with no corresponding character).

Comment: that is, usually to `-1` although it might be any negative integer in general

Comment: @MichaelElliott And the `%` is because you aren't printing a newline `\n`.

Answer (score 9):

`putchar(c)` means to output the character which corresponds to `c` (which is a number) in the character encoding in use (usually ASCII).

There is no character which is encoded as `EOF` (that's the whole point of `EOF`).

The stipulation to "print value of EOF" does not mean "print the character whose code is `EOF`" (since there is none). Instead they most likely mean to print the integer with the same value as `EOF` on your system.

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("EOF: %d\n", EOF);
}
```

`EOF` is not a printable char as you expected.

Comment: EOF is not even a character